# Print a message instead of a number if certain conditions are met

Tags: python

I need to build a program that prints all the numbers between 1 to n, if we have a number that is divisible by 7 print "boom!" instead of a number, if the number has the digit 7, print "boom!" instead and if both print boom-boom!. For example, for n=18:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
boom-boom!
8
9
10
11
12
13
boom!
15
16
boom!
18
```

This is what I did so far, I have almost no experience in coding so I must be doing something wrong here:

```
n=100
intlst=range(n+1)
strlst=str(range(n+1))

for i in intlst:
 print(i)
 if i % 7 == 0:
   print("boom")
 if "7" in strlst:
   print("boop")
```

The modulo works but the string check doesn't. I tried to run it without the modulu part and I just get the normal 1 to 100 print.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Can you think of a way of getting the last digit of a number? That would help :)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy turning the integer to a string and checking if the digit is there ?

Comment: Your `strlst` as it is now will contain a string that includes all the numbers - convert the `i` number to a string instead :)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I understand that any digit can be 7, not just the last one.

Comment: @Roberto: indeed, I didn't read the question properly, sorry.

Comment: This question seems to be homework and a variant of fizz-buzz test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
n = 100
for i in xrange(1, n + 1):
    s = str(i)
    if "7" in s and i % 7 == 0:
        print "boom-boom!"
    elif "7" in s or i % 7 == 0:
        print "boom!"
    else:
        print i
```

Comment: Very elagant, I didn't think in terms of logical operators at all. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, but others were trying to make you figure out the solution yourself, it would've been better for you if you reasoned about it instead of seeing it ready... :/

Answer (score 4):

If you're new to coding, a good idea is to write down your algorithm in a simple, "pseudocode" language. This way you won't get overwhelmed by weird names and functions. So if I understand correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
for each *number* in the range [1,100] do:
    if *number* is divisible by 7 and contains the number 7 then print "boom-boom!"
    else if *number* has digit 7 in it or is divisible by 7, then print "boom!"
    else print *number*
```

Now all you gotta do is translate this algorithm into python, and realli has beaten me to it ;)

Comment: Yeah I did exactly that but I had problems with ordering the code and the right commands.